# Deleting and recreating an element with React

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to get Chart.js to work with React.js and I'm close.

I have React rendering the correct graph, and when I change state the new chart is drawn overtop of the other one. The issue is that the hover events are clearly being left on the `canvas`, and moving the mouse over it flashes all versions of the graph that have been made before.

This is a bug in Chart.js as far as I know, **and the solution is to delete the `canvas` element and replace it with a new canvas element.**

So I have this code, which gets the graph on the page:

```
var LineChart = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id="lineHolder" className="graphHolder">
        <h2 className="sectionHeader">Earnings per day</h2>
        <canvas id="lineChart" width="688" height="286"></canvas>
      </div>
    );
  },
  ctx: {},
  lineChart: {},
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.drawChart();
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    this.drawChart();
  },
  drawChart: function() {
    var lineData = {
      labels: this.props.dates,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Earnings",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: this.props.earnings,
      }]
    }
    this.ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
    this.lineChart = new Chart(this.ctx).Line(lineData);
  }
});
```

But I can't think of the "react way" to delete and replace that canvas element, every time it needs to be redraw.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you think to empty that canvas like $("lineChart").empty() before assgine the value

Comment: @dhavalpatel, this app doesn't have jQuery right now. I may add it for some things later, but I'd like to keep this part in the style of React.js if possible

Comment: document.getElementById("lineChart").innerHTML = "";

Comment: Please *do not* use direct DOM manipulation methods like innerHTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, you want to change the view every time the props or state change. If you're using a DOM manipulation library, such as Chart.js, this is where the React lifecycle methods come in handy.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

You can use `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate` (depending on what suits) to compare the next state to the previous state.

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    /* Optionally include logic comparing nextProps or nextState
     * to this.props or this.state
     */
    this.lineChart.clear();
}
```

Just make sure that it's props/state changes that drive the changes in the Chart.

I don't know much about this apparent Chart.js bug. But if you do need to re-render the canvas element each time, I would suggest placing a `key` attribute on the canvas element.

```
<canvas key={this.uniqueKey()} id="lineChart" width="688" height="286"></canvas>
```

Quite what `this.uniqueKey()` produces hard to say. But it needs to be different every time the props or state change. And only resort this if simpler methods like `Chart#clear()` (or possibly `Chart#destroy()`) fail.

Comment: Look at that, destroy did the trick! Thanks for looking in to this. Out of curiousity, would Math.random() have been an acceptable key, or would that trigger something terrible?

Comment: `Math.random()` is not a good enough key because of its unfortunate non-uniqueness. refer to the bottom of https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html A predictable incrementing number would probably be better.

Comment: So I've had to go through and add a counter to every canvas element. I have multiple "tabs" in the app, and the canvas needs to be rebooted when you switch away from a tab and back to it. Do I need to worry about much a performance hit for this? The only other option I could think of was rerendering the entire tab on every tab-change, which seems worse.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var LineChart = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id="lineHolder" className="graphHolder">
        <h2 className="sectionHeader">Earnings per day</h2>
        <canvas ref="lineChart" key={this.state.canvasUpdateToggle} width="688" height="286"></canvas>
      </div>
    );
  },
  ctx: {},
  lineChart: {},
  getInitialState:function(){
    return {canvasUpdateToggle:"0"};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.drawChart();
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    this.drawChart();
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps:function(){
    var canvasUpdateToggle = this.state.canvasUpdateToggle == 0? 1: 0;
    this.setState({"canvasUpdateToggle":canvasUpdateToggle});
  },
  drawChart: function() {
    var lineData = {
      labels: this.props.dates,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Earnings",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: this.props.earnings,
      }]
    }
    this.ctx = this.refs.lineChart.getContext("2d");
    this.lineChart = new Chart(this.ctx).Line(lineData);
  }
});
```